# Unity C# and Array Sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine

So I know how to sort arrays in php and keep the keys but I am having some trouble in unity.

Lets say i have an array
itemcost = new int[10];

```
    itemcost[1] = 100;
    itemcost[2] = 300;
    itemcost[3] = 900;
    itemcost[4] = 300;
    itemcost[5] = 100;
    itemcost[6] = 300;
```

what is the best way to sort this descending so highest cost up top BUT keep the array keys so I can get the corresponding def and att values?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Don't use arrays of separate values, use an array (or list) of classes that contain properties for all related values.

Comment: Of course that would be ideal but the problem is while this is easy for me to do in php, in c# this is proving much harder to do!

Comment: say I have def, att, cost, name attribute for each item what would be the best way to store them sort via att (descending) and then get say the 2nd item in the list?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: By the way, an array index starts at zero

Answer (score 2):

> Sort Generic List or Array of a class/structure based on class property or element property

create one class to hold cost and its index then sort array or list of this class

you can event add def, att, cost, name attribute for each item in class

here is example

```
public class CostData
    {
        public int Cost;
        public int ID;
        public CostData(int CostAmount, int CostID)
        {
            Cost = CostAmount;
            ID = CostID;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CostData> itemcost = new List<CostData> {
                                                    new CostData(100, 1),
                                                    new CostData(300, 2),
                                                    new CostData(900, 3),
                                                    new CostData(300, 4),
                                                    new CostData(100, 5),
                                                    new CostData(300, 6)
                                                   };

        List<CostData> SortedList = itemcost.OrderByDescending((CostData i) => i.Cost).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(SortedList[0].Cost.ToString() + " on index " + SortedList[0].ID.ToString());

        // you can do same with Arrray

        CostData[] itemcost2 = new CostData[] {
                                                    new CostData(100, 1),
                                                    new CostData(300, 2),
                                                    new CostData(900, 3),
                                                    new CostData(300, 4),
                                                    new CostData(100, 5),
                                                    new CostData(300, 6)
                                                   };

        CostData[] SortedList2 = itemcost2.OrderByDescending((CostData i) => i.Cost).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(SortedList2[0].Cost.ToString() + " on index " + SortedList2[0].ID.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: He needs to keep the index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, itemcost.Length)
              .OrderByDescending(index => itemcost[index])
              .ToList();

result.ForEach(index => Console.WriteLine(index + " : " + itemcost[index]));
```

Will return a list of index of item cost sorted in order.

See [here](https://repl.it/repls/SentimentalHelpfulSpider)

Answer (score 1):

There is [Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Each key in the keysArray has a corresponding item in the itemsArray. When a key is repositioned during the sorting, the corresponding item in the itemsArray is similarly repositioned. Therefore, the itemsArray is sorted according to the arrangement of the corresponding keys in the keysArray.

```
int[] indices = new int[itemcost.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < itemcost.Length; i++)
{
   indices[i] = i;
}

Array.Sort(itemcost, indices);
```